# Can a pre made jam be thickened into pate de fruit?

Tags: dessert, candy, pastry

I have a wonderful locally made jam and want to turn it into fruit de pate to sell alongside the jam in my market. Can I add more pectin to the jam after heating it to thicken it into a jelly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a discussion on [Jam to Pate de Fruit?](https://forums.egullet.org/topic/153251-jam-to-pate-de-fruit/) at [eGullet Forums](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjdiaHcvqPuAhWOg-AKHfQ8A5cQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.egullet.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw2oPGEv4AEK2oiHOoankT85).

Question posted by [pastryani](https://forums.egullet.org/profile/74980-pastryani/):

> Is it possible to make PDF from jam or jelly?  Jam is essentially a more fluid version of PDF, so I would think that I could either (1) boil off extra liquid from the jam until it's thicker, or (2) warm the jam and add a bit of pectin to it to thicken it.  If I were to try the latter, anyone know what amount of pectin would be needed?  Thanks!

One answer by [ElainaA](https://forums.egullet.org/profile/71927-elainaa/):

> I've done (an unsophisticated) PDF from jam many times. The recipe is from one of the first candy books I bought, years ago, Weinstein's The Ultimate Candy Book. It uses gelatin: 2 envelopes of unflavored gelatin, softened in 1/3 cup. 3/4 c. granulated sugar and 1/3 c. water combined and heated to a boil. 1 c. jam or marmalade stirred in to dissolve, gelatin added, bring to a boil and cook 2 minutes. Pour into an oiled pan and refrigerate until set.
>
> There is a very similar recipe in Ruth Kendrick's Candymaking called 'fruit jam jellies'.
>
> I'm not sure if these are true PDF but they are good. I've made both with various types of jam or jelly. I preserve so much I have to do something with it.

Conclusion: It is indeed possible, and not hard to do.